# Are all fees becoming "nominal"?

Tags: word-choice

I have noticed a trend that where in the past one would simply use the word "fee", now the phrase "nominal fee" is always used.  As far as I understand, the word "nominal" literally means "in name only".  So a "nominal fee" would be a fee so low that it is not really a fee at all, but is a fee "in name only".

For example a swimming beach in my area has a website where they say "the beach is open to the public for a nominal fee of $8".  In my estimation, $8 is not in any way low... if anything it is average and is probably more on the high side for swimming.  It would have to be on the order of $1 or $2 to be considered "nominal" in my estimation.

Is this a case of misuse of a term, where people think the word "nominal" always goes before the word "fee" and don't understand its meaning?

Comment: I will answer that question for a hefty fee.

Comment: That's so annoying!   . . . and right up there with crap sold on the TV that touts "and get the second POS free - just pay additional service and handling charge".  Now *shipping* and handling charges are separate presumably, but to me, "service" and "handling" charges are two words for the SAME THING!  (yeesh!)

Comment: @KristinaLopez: Exactly! And why shouldn't handing be included in the price? The only reason to exclude shipping is because different customers might pay different shipping costs. This does not apply to "handling" or "service". Airlines are/were the worst, where they used to tripe the amount advertised through fees, taxes, and levies. Luckily that is now at least forbidden in the EU for plane tickets.

Comment: In electronics-speak, "nominal" usually indicates a plus-or-minus factor, as in, for example, the impedance of a loudspeaker.  Nominally (i.e., in name only), a speaker's impedance may be eight ohms, but in actual use the impedance will fluctuate up or down a bit, but only by a nominal (i.e., minimal) amount, but not enough to re-label it as anything other than an eight-ohm speaker.

Comment: University fees are increasing rapidly. They are not nominal.

Comment: @rhetorician: Economists use "nominal" in a somewhat similar way; for example, a 5% increase in "nominal GDP" means a 5% increase without taking inflation into account (as opposed to "real GDP", which in this case would increase by less than 5%, assuming positive inflation).

Comment: Isn't $8 a rather low fee for swimming by a blue whale?

Comment: @rhetorician Nominally 8 ohm speakers really are 8 ohms "in name only": it is a representative value that is written on them, which causes them to be called 8 ohm speakers.

Comment: The term "nominal fee" can be used to indicate that the payment doesn't meet technical or legal requirements to actually be considered a fee. For example, some jurisdictions require fees to go solely to the organization that provides the service for which the fee is charged. Some require the fee to be based on the actual cost to provide the service. If these requirements are not met, it is a "nominal fee", called a fee but not meeting the legal requirements to actually be one.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That obviously very much depends on location. I certainly would not understand 'nominal fee' in that way in the UK.

Comment: This is not misuse of a term. This is evolution of meaning. http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/nominal

Comment: @MετάEd, none of the definitions you referenced covers the situation of every single fee, which is how it is being used

Comment: This premise (that instead of writing "fee", "nominal fee" is now always used) needs to be defended in the question, not stated as if it were fact. What's going on here is not a compounding of "nominal" and "fee", but an evolution of the meaning of "nominal", possibly because people don't remember what "nominal" actually means.

Comment: As Peter De Vries once observed, some things are nominal in name only.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are absolutely right: this is an inflation of the word "nominal", which ought to mean "(so low as to be) in name only". You would normally not name the exact amount if you say it's a "nominal fee"; you just say this:

> The beach is open for a nominal fee.

You *might* add the actual fee in brackets. Perhaps whoever made that sign didn't quite understand the proper use of "nominal".

Comment: It’s these people who write [“notional fee”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22notional%20fee%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) who really bug me.

Comment: They should really be saying, "This beach is not free.  You have to pay to gain admittance".

Comment: @tchrist - "notional fee"?  That's crossed from annoying into plain ignorant!

Comment: @tchrist, KristinaLopez .  That depends. "Nominal" means the real amount, and is used in situations where  **you pay the fake amount**. "Notional" means "fake amount", but used in situations where **you pay the real amount**.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notional_amount

Comment: See here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364842/the-many-meanings-of-nominal The real meaning of nominal may well be "within normal limits"

Comment: @Joshua: Well, I think many people would find that meaning unacceptable? Probably contamination from *normal*. When one means "normal", why not say it?

Comment: @Cerberus: The first answer gives a more straightforward derivation, direct from "as named".