# The many meanings of "nominal"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I work in software in a technology field, and hear the word *nominal* tossed around quite a bit. Sometimes I have a hard time understanding which meaning people are intending. Maybe I have a mental block, but this word really gets me. For example, Dictionary.com gives as many as [ten definitions](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nominal)!

> **adjective**
>
> 1. being such in name only; so-called; putative: a nominal treaty; the nominal head of the country.
> 2. (of a price, consideration, etc.) named as a mere matter of form, being trifling in comparison with the actual value; minimal.
> 3. of, relating to, or constituting a name or names.
> 4. Grammar. of, relating to, or producing a noun or nouns: a nominal suffix. functioning as or like a noun.
> 5. assigned to a person by name: nominal shares of stock.
> 6. containing, bearing, or giving a name or names.
> 7. (of money, income, or the like) measured in an amount rather than in real value: Nominal wages have risen 50 percent, but real wages are down because of inflation.
> 8. Aerospace. performing or achieved within expected, acceptable limits; normal and satisfactory: The mission was nominal throughout.
> 9. Slang. done smoothly as expected: The space shot was nominal, proceeding without a hitch.
>
> **noun**
>
> 10. Grammar. a word or group of words functioning as a noun.

The usage I'm seeing it in right now is “When the system enters this mode, these portions of it are active and **power consumption is nominal.**”

I think the author intended meaning #8 or possibly meaning #2. I'm leaning towards #8.

I can't just ask the author of the paper which meaning they meant, so which would it be?

In the future when I hear someone use the word *nominal*, I intend to pull out my list of synonyms and ask them which one they mean (if any!).

Comment: And that's not even all of the meanings. In data science (and especially cartography/GIS) "nominal" means essentially "qualitative". http://www.mymarketresearchmethods.com/types-of-data-nominal-ordinal-interval-ratio/

Comment: [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nominal) has synonyms for the two or three most widely used 'versions'  of nominal. But the meanings are interrelated. If something is nominal, as in 'being in name only' (say a nominal head of a country), then the use of nominal for 2  follows that one: a nominal amount can be thought of  an amount in name only, or a trifle. Someone not really being the head is similar to something not really having much of a cost. More technical uses (8) are like a technical use of any word: generally restricted to that field.

Comment: Can you give more context with your example, please.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The best I can do is paraphrase. So here goes: "When the system enters this mode, these portions of it are active and power consumption is nominal." I know that's not a lot of context, but it's all I can give.

Comment: I still couldn't assess whether sense 2 or 8 above is intended. I'm still inclined to guess 2, though (nominal = of an insignificant amount; not worth worrying about at all).

Answer (score 4):

"Nominal" as used in engineering typical means pretty much #8 in your list.

That is, if a component is rated as consuming 100 watts, and it is actually consuming something close to that, then the power consumption is nominal.  "As named" or "as expected".

Comment: Aren't the other senses allowed? In maths, for instance, 'difference' retains its everyday meaning as well as the 'mod (A-B)' sense.

Comment: That's what I thought too, until I thought more about #2. They _probably_ meant #8, but it's not clear.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, of course the other senses are allowed, but what the example means is more along the lines of #8.  michael.hor257k's answer is perfectly reasonable in other situations, meaning "comparatively little". But as you know, "Context is King".

Comment: I've even known people to make mistakes. Context is often insufficient, and here I'd only go as far as 'there is an 80% probability that sense #8 is intended'.

Comment: This is clearly not the type of "nominal" here, but I'd like to call it out: in a software context (as the asker said they work), "nominal" could also mean name-based, e.g. [nominal type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).

Answer (score 1):

With regard to:

> ... and power consumption is nominal.

it probably means *very small*. Although the dictionary definition restricts this meaning to price:

> 2 (of a price or amount of money) very small; far below the real value
>   or cost : *some firms charge only a nominal fee for the service*.
>   New Oxford American Dictionary

it could be extended to *cost* in fuel consumption.

Of course, without context this is no more than an educated guess.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nominal) has "insignificant" as one of its definitions, which certainly fits the "very small" meaning.  "3c: TRIFLING, INSIGNIFICANT"